# How do I write casual text in Phpstorm without saving a real file

Tags: phpstorm

I many times want to keep a bunch of text and copied text in a random unsaved file while I work. When I use Phpstorm, it doesn't let you create a new file that doesn't really exist and so I have nowhere to write my rubbish.

Is it possible with Phpstorm to do this or do I have to rely on something like Notepad++ for that?

Comment: I used this analogy before: PHPStorm is an IDE, Notepad++ is a text editor. You wouldn't use chef's knives to spread peanut butter on bread.

Comment: assuming you didnt have to wash up, why not? :) jj, does that mean it isnt possible?

Comment: heh, I know it's not the response you were looking for. PHPStorm wants to keep you in a static environment. That means keeping you confined to the files within your workspace.PHPStorm *can* handle  files outside of the workspace but it doesn't really want to.

Comment: Ha ha, so you arent gonna let me in the secret cos its not good for me :(

Comment: There *might* be something you can do with tasks http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/tasks.html. They appear to be notes that are saved as part of the internal project meta-data.

Comment: will check it out, probably best as you say to keep PHPstorm clean and keep the random stuff in the text editor. Cheers for your help

Comment: Have a look at **Scratch** plugin (`Settings | Plugins | Browse repositories...`) -- it's something between real and virtual file ("in between" -- simply because Editor only works with files)

Comment: @LazyOne will do, thanks for the tip on the plugin repository too! Gonna look it up soon